# New iPhone App - How to Choose which Xcode Template to Use?

Tags: iphone, xcode, project, xcode-template

In general I'd like to understand which templates to use when, when I'm making new iPhone apps.  Could anyone offer some guidelines, tips, rules-of-thumb?

Also, how much should I agonize over this?  If I start off with the wrong one, can I add the missing pieces manually, is it hard?

For reference here are the choices I'm seeing:

- Navigation-Based Application
- OpenGL ES Application
- Tab Bar Application
- Utility Application
- View-Based Application
- Window-Based Application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start with your prototype and possibly wireframes and then the correct template should jump out at you.

If this does not work for you, then:

1. If your app looks like 'Contacts', use Navigation-Based Application.
2. If you're writing a game (or something that looks like one), then OpenGL.
3. If you're writing something like 'Calendar', then use Tab Bar App.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Acctually, the Tab Bar is more related to the "Clock" App.

Answer (score 20):

In [iPhone Development Quick Start](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/100-iPhone_Development_Quick_Start/iphone_development_quick_start.html), from Apple, you have a brief description of each:

> - **Navigation-Based Application.** An application that presents data
>     hierarchically, using multiple
>     screens. The Contacts application is
>     an example of a navigation-based
>     application.
> - **OpenGL ES Application.** An application that uses an OpenGL
>     ES–based view to present images or
>     animation.
> - **Tab Bar Application.** An application that presents a radio
>     interface that lets the user choose
>     from several screens. The Clock
>     application is an example of a tab bar
>     application.
> - **Utility Application.** An application that implements a main
>     view and lets the user access a
>     flipside view to perform simple
>     customizations. The Stocks application
>     is an example of a utility
>     application.
> - **View-Based Application.** An application that uses a single view to
>     implement its user interface.
> - **Window-Based Application.** This template serves as a starting point
>     for any application, containing an
>     application delegate and a window. Use
>     this template when you want to
>     implement your own view hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know what template to use, it seems like your idea needs some refining. Usually, the app idea lends itself specifically to one of the templates.

And no, you shouldn't agonize over this. If you start with the wrong template, you can add the missing pieces without much effort. You can even create a brand new project with the template you want and see how they do it, and just copy that in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Also note - there aren't that many templates.
Create a new project for each one, Build and Run immediately, and you'll get an idea what you need.