# How to Choose which Xcode Template to Use?

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates, project

what if i have ecommerce application? 
like i have
1)sale page 
2)list of product page(grid view and list view)
3)detail of product
4) zoom images for that product.

what kind of template should i use?
i refer this post but its not clear.
[New iPhone App - How to Choose which Xcode Template to Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366899/new-iphone-app-how-to-choose-which-xcode-template-to-use/1850134#1850134)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a similar application on the AppStore you may like to see how they have approached it, generally there is something similar that can help you clarify how you would like your application to function.

From the sounds of your application idea you would probably be best served by the Navigation template. But after all it is only a template, you can completely change the structure of the application later without needing to start another project.

Comment: I don't recommend looking to see how a similar application was designed.  You don't want to create a "me too" application, there are already far too many in the App Store.  If you don't have design skills to help you, then go hire a designer.  If your app is going to be successful, you can't simply copy what other people have done.

Comment: @marcc I don't believe this is what the answer is saying, it's saying look for "something similar that can help you clarify how you would like your application to function." This is hardly saying "take their design" as you seem to be inferring, it is (as is the question) referring to getting ideas for good functionality and layout, not stealing entire interface designs.

Comment: This is true, although I would add that to create a design that is more effective than the competition you should at least be aware of how the competition has approached the problem. No use reinventing the wheel in isolation (unless you have a brilliant idea!)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a hierarchy of views in which you go from general to specific information, then you want the navigation template.

However, most of the time, the templates are just starting points for learning. In most cases, you will have an app that is a combination so you start with the generic windows-based template and then flesh it out yourself.

Comment: thank you guys, your suggestion really helps( as i am really new in Apple environment),now i was looking at Apple's sample code ,in some app they are creating everything programatically and in some they use XIB files, so i was wondering which one is good and simple to implement.

thanks once again,

Comment: It's largely a matter of preference. If you're using routine interface elements then IB is usually easier and quicker. If you want to use highly customized elements you usually end up hand coding.