# Xcode template choices, impacts to finishing product

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Recently I was planning on starting a project on Xcode and using the language Swift.

I have a decent understanding of how to use a Playground, but not so much on creating applications and using simulators.

Can someone tell me the difference in the templates and which  [template/templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d57dP.png) are effective in developing apps for beginners?

Comment: subject to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/5175709) meta post, this question is not to be deemed as a duplicate of [this 7 year old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366899/new-iphone-app-how-to-choose-which-xcode-template-to-use). Though it could be a duplicate of another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want your app to look like

Master-Detail Application looks like this:

**L**andscape view: Left side is MasterviewController, right side is detailViewController.
**P**ortrait View: you would only see the master, and upon clicking it would open an only detailViewController with a back button to the master.

[image: left side is the master, right side is the detail]

---

Tab Bar looks like this:
You have different tabs at the bottom.

### [image]

Page-Based Application looks like this:
AFAIK It's usually used for first demo pages. Or sometimes for books. I have never used it myself.
[image]

---

Game is for games.

---

Single View Application is a vanilla application. Has nothing but a single viewcontroller. For **l**earning purposes **b**est to start here.

---

Side note. None of these templates mean you are tied to them. You can always adjust them accordingly, but it's just that templates make your intent more clear and reduce the early build up.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what kind of application. I'd generally go for the default single view application. Obviously if you're creating a game you'd use a game template..

There's very little difference between most of them. It's just a little starter

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation. However, will a game template affect my development in the creation process in the long run or do they both have the same result?

Comment: No, basically it just automatically generates different things for each one. Nothing that can't be created manually later.